# Glimpse works locally, but not deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

Locally, mapped to a virtual directory in IIS, everything works just fine. When I deploy the site to Azure, I can still access Glimpse.axd and set the cookie (IP reported is in the allowed list), but the Glimpse icon is not showing up on any pages.

There are no javascript errors reported by the browser. Checking the page source, the two javascript include files that should be injected into the page at the end of the body are not being sent.

Setting `loggingEnabled="true"` in web.config generates the same log locally, which works, as it does on Azure, which does not work (virtual directory and requestId excepting). From the Azure log:

```
2012-09-25 17:54:13.0271|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|BeginRequest handling complete for requestId 4da70989-d89b-46ef-80c6-43bd6f5a7ce1 (/cart)|
2012-09-25 17:54:13.1571|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|get_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:13.1571|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|set_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:13.1571|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|GetType method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:13.1571|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|MemberwiseClone method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:28.5420|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|get_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:28.5420|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|set_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:28.5420|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|GetType method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:28.5420|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|MemberwiseClone method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5812|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|get_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5812|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|set_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5812|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|GetType method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5831|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|MemberwiseClone method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5831|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|get_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5831|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|set_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5831|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|GetType method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5831|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|MemberwiseClone method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5988|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|get_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5988|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|set_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5988|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|GetType method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.5988|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|MemberwiseClone method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.7874|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|PostRequestHandlerExecute handling complete for requestId 4da70989-d89b-46ef-80c6-43bd6f5a7ce1 (/cart)|
2012-09-25 17:54:30.8978|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|PostReleaseRequestState handling complete for requestId 4da70989-d89b-46ef-80c6-43bd6f5a7ce1 (/cart)|
2012-09-25 17:54:31.0277|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|Glimpse JSON payload created for requestId 4da70989-d89b-46ef-80c6-43bd6f5a7ce1 (/cart)|
2012-09-25 17:54:31.1411|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|Glimpse output generated for requestId 4da70989-d89b-46ef-80c6-43bd6f5a7ce1 (/cart)|
2012-09-25 17:54:31.1411|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|RequestId 4da70989-d89b-46ef-80c6-43bd6f5a7ce1 (/cart) persisted|
2012-09-25 17:54:31.1411|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|EndRequest handling complete for requestId 4da70989-d89b-46ef-80c6-43bd6f5a7ce1 (/cart)|
```

I used Glimpse successfully in development and deployed to a testing server on Azure last year. I haven't had a need to use it since then until now. A lot has changed in the project, but this is the same solution that worked a year ago. I'm just trying to track down a problem that is only occurring in Azure right now.

Any suggestions on where I can start looking? I'm using MVC3 and .NET 4.0 with Glimpse 0.87

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that the IP address you have configured in web.config is not the actual IP address Azure's infrastructure passes through.

The good news is, we have removed the IP filtering feature from the Glimpse 1.0 release candidate, which is currently available as a prerelease package on NuGet.

If you continue to have issues after upgrading, please submit a bug report on [Glimpse's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues).